# How do I send skype messages from google sheets script editor (skype name and username in google sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Please send a code for this project. I made a code to open it in new tab but I don't know how to make the script type the name in the search skype and the message appears in the text box and automatically sends it.